# How can I run ZF2 Validation on a model without a form?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am trying to run validation on a class in ZF2.  I have followed the Album example and understand how the validator works with a form but how can I run it against an array?  Below is the code from the example.

```
 $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
 $form->setData($request->getPost());
 if ($form->isValid()) {
```

In my case I do not have a form but have an array of data that I want to exchange to the class.  How can I validate this array?  How do I run the isValid function?  Do I need to bind the array to a new form and then run the validation??  It seems like there would be a cleaner way.

Many Thanks,
M

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575074/949273

Comment: @tasmanisk this works!  many thanks.  I can ask a follow up but how do I get the message to display?  Is there a way to populate the help class (as it does in the album example)?  They use the if it is valid else do nothing (which reloads the page with the messages).  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Filter that extends to `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter`

```
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
class AlbumFilter extends InputFilter {
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->add(array(
                'name'     => 'title',
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Title is required.',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
    }
```

}

Then in your controller:

```
$AlbumFilter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AlbumFilter'); // assuming you have added AlbumFilter in your Module.php
$AlbumFilter->setData($data);
if ($AlbumFilter->isValid()) {
    // do something
}
```